# Pushing from local master to a remote non-master branch

Tags: git, github, git-push

On my local machine, I have a repository set up as the following

```
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: git@github.com:me/my_project.git
  Push  URL: git@github.com:me/my_project.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    mac-master tracked
    master     tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (local out of date)
```

There is only `master` branch *locally*, and I want to always push my local master to the *remote* `mac-master` branch. Should I just do:

```
git push origin master:mac-master
```

every time I need to push? If not, what is the correct way of doing it?

Comment: It's very satisfying to read a well-formed question.  You give all of the needed information, and describe exactly what you want. Thank you. +1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you always want to do it, run

```
$ git push -u remote master:mac-master
```

*once*. The `-u` flag will set up options so that subsequently you can do:

```
$ git push
```

to push `master` to `mac-master` on `remote`.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. After the first git command, I checked `git remote show origin` again, and it still shows `Local ref configured for 'git push': master pushes to master (local out of date)`, how should I interpret this? Can I interpret that all the pushes will go from my local `master` to the remote `master`?

Answer (score 5):

You can change the branch on the remote that your branch is tracking by:

```
git branch --set-upstream   branch_name   your_remote/other_branch_name
```

This way, pushes of `branch_name` to `your_remote` will be done to `other_branch_name`.